# Find the area using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> What is the area defined by the curves $y = \sin x$ and $y = \cos x$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{4}$?

I think it's $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} [\cos x - \sin x]\, \mathbb{d}x$$ but I'm not sure if my step is right or not.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your integral is correct.  If you have two curves above the $x$-axis on an interval $[a,b]$, then the area between them is given by $$\int_{a}^{b}(\text{top curve} - \text{bottom curve})\,dx.$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $\cos(0)=1,\sin(0)=0$ now find the points for which the two curves intersect:
$$\sin(x)=\cos(x)\Rightarrow \tan(x)=1$$
$$x=\arctan(1)=\pi/4$$
What this means is that for: $0\le x\le \pi/4,\,\cos(x)\ge\sin(x)$. And so if you want the area between two functions that is the same as the integral of the greater function minus the integral of the lesser function, in this case:
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(x)dx-\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin(x)dx$$
So yes you are correct. If you did it the other way around you would simply end up with a negative value and since we are considering area here it is clear that the sign is just wrong

Answer (score 2):

To concur with you, and demonstrate visually, I graphed both functions from $-\pi$ to $\pi$:

[image]

Between $x= 0$ and $x=\pi/4$, we see that $y=\cos x > y= \sin x$.  So your set up is spot on.  By noting $$\int_{o\to {\pi/4}} (\cos x- \sin x)\,\mathrm dx,$$

we find the area below $y = \cos x$ and subtract the area below $y=\sin x$, giving us the area between the two curves, on that interval.

Comment: Whenever you determining which of two functions to subtract from the other, I recommend graphing them.  Wolfram.Alpha.com is quick for this purpose.  It only took me a few minutes to find [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D+cos+x+and+y%3D%5Csin+x%2C+x+from+-pi+to+pi).

Comment: The lower bound seems to be o not 0.  ;)

Comment: @amWhy  May I know why you are re-editing all my suggestions with only minor changes? While on other hand, I am putting lot of efforts in editing? Please let me know if I am making any mistake in editing. Thanks!

Comment: @Rahit You still get your two points, but your edits sometimes go too far: Capitalizing every first letter in a title, or including inappropriate bold text.  You do a fine job with formatting mathjax, so I appreciate your efforts, and only fine tune them.  I do not reject them.   I've seen improvement in some of those matters.  The purpose of suggesting edits is to format what isn't formatted, not to transform it into what you would write if you were asking.  You are also incredibly helpful in transcribing text from images,   and you deserve credit for that!

Comment: There is no way for a reviewer to comment to a suggested edit.  Don't second guess yourself!  You are doing well.  But I learned a lot, early on, from users who improved my suggested edits, so I'm only trying to be helpful.  And once you reach 2000 in rep, you can edit unincumbered!  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @amWhy. My only purpose was to ask if I am making any mistake, and not to demean your efforts. I appreciate your efforts in making me learn about edits. Thanks for letting me know mine mistakes, and fine-tuning them with your edits. I will keep in mind that purpose of edits is to format what isn't formatted and not to transform as if It is our question. I know this is replying late but you mistakenly have mentioned some `Rahit`, instead of me `Rohit` :)

Comment: Apologies for misspelling your name, Rohit!  :)  thanks for correcting me.